# Why we could run the algorithm on Linear Bounded Automata?

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages

Suppose there is an algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ for the problem $\Pi$ that halts on any instance $x\in\Pi$. Someone tells me that we can run $\mathcal{A}$ on Linear Bounded Automata, but I can't understand why.

My background in Theory of Computation says that the problem $\Pi$ could be a decidable language and maybe can't be in Context-Sensetive class so we can't run  $\mathcal{A}$ on an LBA. Finally,  $\mathcal{A}$ can run on the TM machines.